# Change C++ compiler for cmake under TravisCI

Tags: c++, cmake, travis-ci, biicode

As far I know the best way to change the target C++ compiler used by cmake is to change the `CXX` environment variable just before the call to cmake:

```
$ export CXX="clang++" && cmake --build
```

The Travis CI build sets the `CXX` and `CC` accordingly to the settings of the build. So if you have this in your `.travis.yml`:

```
language: cpp
compiler: 
  - gcc
  - clang

script:
  - cmake --build
  - ./bin/foo
```

The first time `cmake` should use GCC and Clang on the latter isn't?

Instead, the GCC build compiles just fine (Its the default compiler used by cmake), but the Clang version uses GCC too:

> 0.01s$ echo $CC $CXX
>   clang clang++
>   The command "echo $CC $CXX" exited with 0.
>
> 0.02s$ $CXX --version
>   clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu Thread model: posix
>
> Running: cmake  -G "Unix Makefiles" -Wno-dev  ../cmake
>   -- The C compiler identification is GNU
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

I even tried to set those variables again just before the call:

```
- if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then export CXX="clang++" && cmake --build; fi
- if [ "$CXX" == "g++" ];     then export CXX="g++"     && cmake --build; fi
```

*Which has no much sense I think...*

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/Manu343726/Turbo/jobs/33889113) is the successful build using GCC, and [here](https://travis-ci.org/Manu343726/Turbo/jobs/33889114) the (Supposed to be) clang build.

My question is: **How I can change the compiler used by cmake under Travis CI?**

[Here](https://github.com/Manu343726/Turbo/blob/master/.travis.yml) is my .travis.yml.

Comment: `The first time cmake should use GCC and Clang on the latter isn't?` this approach should work fine. However I prefer to use cmake toolchains, it's more flexible. Example: [linux](https://github.com/forexample/hunter-simple/blob/master/.travis.yml) and [mac](https://github.com/forexample/hunter-simple/blob/macosx/.travis.yml)

Comment: @ruslo but doesn't work. As you can see [here](https://travis-ci.org/Manu343726/Turbo/jobs/33889114), cmake gets rid completely from the value of `CXX`, which is `clang++`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Explanation

In your `.travis.yml` we see:

```
- if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then export CXX="clang++" && bii cpp:build; fi
- if [ "$CXX" == "g++" ];     then export CXX="g++"     && bii cpp:build; fi
```

`biicode`'s command `bii cpp:build` runs CMake with `biicode`'s default generator which is `"Unix Makefiles"` for UNIX platform (GNU toolchain). Read about it: [Biicode C++ documentation - Generators and IDEs](https://github.com/biicode/docs/blob/master/c++/ides.rst).

This behaviour is seen in your logs: `Running: cmake  -G "Unix Makefiles" -Wno-dev  ../cmake` (https://travis-ci.org/Manu343726/Turbo/jobs/33889114, line 257)

CMake not always looks for environment variables `CXX/CC` (as stated in [CMake FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F)). It depends on selected generator. It works for me when I call CMake with no generator (my travis file: https://github.com/quepas/Graph-ene/blob/master/.travis.yml).

### Solutions

- Use CMake alone with `cmake -D` format described in method 2 ([CMake FAQ - How do I use a different compiler?](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F))
- Setup `biicode` to use proper CMake's generator ([Biicode C++ Configuration](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/cpp-commands.html#bii-cpp-configure-configure-your-project)) or use `biicode`'s custom toolchain ([Biicode - Using custom toolchain](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/building.html#using-a-custom-toolchain))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a matrix. This is especially useful if you have many different compilers (eg. gcc5, gcc6, clang3.7, clang3.8):

```
language: generic # Works better in most cases

matrix:
    include:
    - env: CXX=g++ CC=gcc
      # additional apt settings if needed
    - env: CXX=clang++ CC=clang

script:
    - ...
```

If you have different versions of a compiler this can be extended:

```
[…]
matrix:
    include:
    - env: CXX=g++-5 CC=gcc-5
    - env: CXX=g++-6 CC=gcc-6
    - env: CXX=clang++-3.8 CC=clang-3.8
[…]
```

It also doesn't duplicate the script steps and keeps the file clean of *if…  else…* parts.

https://travis-ci.org/RhysU/descendu/builds/158055261